# Group by clause - output is not as expected

Tags: sql

Below is my sql query to get the list of dates from a table.

```
select t2.counter_date as myDates from table1 t1;
```

output:

```
myDates

2014-03-14 00:00:00
2014-05-11 00:00:00
2014-11-03 00:00:00
2014-12-23 00:00:00
2015-01-12 00:00:00
2015-08-08 00:00:00
2016-03-14 00:00:00
2017-03-14 00:00:00
2017-03-19 00:00:00
```

Below is the solution:

```
select min(t1.counter_date) as oldDate,max(t1.counter_date) as latestDate from table1 t1;
```

Comment: How do `min()` and `max()` not work with a timestamp?

Comment: What's the error you get when you try it on timestamp?

Comment: Not giving any error but same date is repeating in oldestDate and latestDate columns.

Comment: `status = 'current' and status not in('Failed','Blocked')` equals to `status = 'current'`

Comment: show us sample data and expected output. Now it is not clear what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In the following [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b8de6f9d6ec9c2787dd9e26d8899c597) you can see that your query is giving the correct results. The problem must be in your data.

EDIT: after the edit it is clear where the problem is. Once you perform the following query:

```
SELECT min(date), max(date)
FROM tab
GROUP BY date
```

than `min(date)` has to be equal to `max(date)` since there is just one date in the group.

Comment: Please see the post, i have edited and added the exact details. I think then it is with the query where i'm using two tables to get the result. Any advice

Comment: @user8190500 - what Radim is saying is that you shouldn't have t2.counter_date in the `GROUP BY` clause.